# Java Client - Server Android На виртуалке работает, на устройстве нет

Tags: java, android, клиент-сервер

Собственно на виртуалке все нормально, на устройстве пишет ошибку времени подключения к серверу. В манифесте указал подключение к интернету:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Код:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText e1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
}

public void send_text(View v) {
    String message = e1.getText().toString();
    myTask mt = new myTask();
    mt.execute(message);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data sent: "+e1.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

class myTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{
    Socket s;
    PrintWriter printWriter;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params){
        try {
            String message = params[0];
            s = new Socket("192.168.137.1", 6001);
            printWriter = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            printWriter.write(message);
            printWriter.flush();
            printWriter.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

```
W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:334)
W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
W/System.err:     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:605)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:554)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:431)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:210)
W/System.err:     at com.example.mfam.agroandroid.MainActivity$myTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:52)
W/System.err:     at com.example.mfam.agroandroid.MainActivity$myTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:44)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: какой андроид на реальном ус-ве? И выложите стэктрейс ошибки

Comment: У Вас сеть вообще организована между PC и Android?

Comment: @Likhanov Андроид 7.1.1

Comment: @woesss первый раз пишу такое приложение, по этому не знаю в чем заключается организация сети. Если есть возможность, подскажите. Спасибо

Comment: Если я правильно понял: сервер на компе, клиент на телефоне. Соответственно они должны быть подключены к одной сети, например к одному роутеру, или напрямую по кабелю, Wi-Fi, Bluetooth... Как они у Вас подключены?

Comment: @woesss к одному Wi-Fi

Comment: Тогда проверьте IP-адрес компа и исправьте в коде.

Comment: @woesss проверил все IPшники, которые выдает ipconfig, так ничего и не заработало

Comment: Со стороны Андроида гадать тут не о чем - проблема либо на стороне сервера (на какую сеть, какой IP, порт он настроен, какие данные и как он обрабатывает), либо в сети (неправильно настроена, блокируется сетевым экраном (брандмауер, файервол...) на роутере, на компьютере. IP-адрес сервера должен совпадать с адресом компьютера в соединении с роутером (обычно что-то вроде 192.168.0.**).

Comment: @woesss поставил верный IP, вчера сидел разбирался с еще одним около студентом, так ничего и не нашли. Потом ночью сделал по данному примеру 1 в 1 https://goo.gl/kSus56 и опять та же ошибка. Может быть я в манифесте, что то накосячил или Wi-Fi не правильно настроил?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибкой было то, что я не знал, что нужно отключать брандмауэр и открывать порт. Открыл порт и все заработало. Всем спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. ты подключаешься с устройства по Wi-fi, то ты должен предоставить устройству пермишины на него. Видимо для эмулятора это не требуется, а для устройства это необходимо.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

И если уже пишешь на Джаве, то придерживайся **lowerCamelStyle** в названии своих методов, а классы пиши с заглавной буквы. Да и поля инкапсулируй :)

Comment: Где Вы увидели, что он проверяет состояние сети?